# Change the timezone in this query to UTC -5 in snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

for this query snowflake keeps pushing unknown timezone.

```
SELECT *
FROM sfprd.corp_posv_customer.r_ctr_connect_logs_bl
WHERE DATE(CONVERT_TIMEZONE('UTC-5', createdat)) = CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1' DAY AND eventname = 'INSERT';
```

I tried this as well:

```
SELECT *
FROM sfprd.corp_posv_customer.r_ctr_connect_logs_bl
WHERE DATE(convert_timezone(createdat,'-05:00')) = CURRENT_DATE - 1
AND eventname = 'INSERT';
```

Comment: Hi - what is the datatype of createdat? If you read the documentation for the CONVERT_TIMEZONE function it explains the allowable timezone name values - and that’s not what you are using in your SQL